# To find work of force $F$ while the physical object of mass $m$ is moving

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, work

I need to solve the problem in this image:

[image: Figure]

The exercise asks to find work of force $F$ while the physical object of mass $m$ is moving from point $A$ to point $B$.

I know from theory that work is the line integral of $F \cdot ds$. Where, "$\cdot$" is the dot product, therefore I need to compute it as follows:

$$F \ ds \ cos \ \theta$$

I know that $F$ is a constant force, displacement is $3d$ (i.e. $3$ times $d$). So, the partial solution is $F3d$, but I have to put a minus sign because force is in the opposite direction from physical object vector. Therefore, final solution is -F3d. But I think that's not right.

In the second part (the arc), I don't have a displacement in the $y$-axis, because object goes up to $y$ and goes down to $y$ so: $y-y = 0$. Therefore, I have displacement only in the $x$-axis, and it's exactly equal to $d$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is really the work of force $F$, does your calculation look right, if it is the work against $F$ or in the presence of $F$ you have to change the sign.

Comment: "if it is the work against F or in the presence of F you have to change the sign" 
it's not the case because it's the work F does. But you mean that work against F is exactly like the work of F but with the opposite sign? the norm of these two forces are actually the same?

Answer (score 2):

Work in second path,

\begin{align} W_2 = \int \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s} \end{align}
\begin{align} W_2= \int Fdscos \theta \end{align}
\begin{align} W_2= \int_{π/2}^{-π/2} Frd\theta cos \theta \end{align}
\begin{align} W_2=-F(2r)=-FD \end{align}

So total work is $ W=-3FD $ .
Where's the problem ?

Comment: Just curious how you visualized your path? My initial instinct would be to use the standard parameterization of a circle, cos(theta) i  + sin(theta)j where using geometry the angle between ds and f is (pi/2 - theta) integrating from pi to 0.  As I feel like you may have been lucky using the same theta for the dot product, as you have in the line element! If f wasn't horizontal it'd be more complex